# Nodemailer con GMail SMTP y autenticación OAuth2 me devuelve 'Invalid status code 401'

Tags: nodejs, email, oauth2, nodemailer

Estoy tratando de hacer un enviador de emails simple usando Nodemailer3, la API de Gmail y autenticación con OAuth2:

Este es mi script:

```
var serverConfig  = {
  gmail: {
      client_user : 'my@email.com',
      client_id : '349...myClientId',
      secret : 'mysecret..123jd123',
      refresh_token : 'x/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-reZuEMeSuJaSERmCVY',
      access_token : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      expires: '3599'
  }
}

// 3LO authentication https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#example-3
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: serverConfig.gmail.client_user,
    clientId: serverConfig.gmail.client_id,
    clientSecret: serverConfig.gmail.secret,
    refreshToken: serverConfig.gmail.refresh_token
  },
});

module.exports = {
    "send": function(_from,_to,_subject,_html,_text){
      // setup email data with unicode symbols
      var mailOptions = {
          from: _from,
          to: _to, // list of receivers
          subject: _subject, // Subject line
          html: _html, // html body
          text: _text // plain text body
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
          if (error) {
              return console.log(error);
          }
          console.log('Message ' + info.messageId + ' sent: %s' + info.response);
      })
  }


}
```

Cuando le paso el access_token al objecto `auth`, el email se envia sin problema. Pero si no especifico el access_token, solo le paso el `refresh_token`, obtengo este error:

```
{ Error: Invalid status code 401
    at ClientRequest.req.on.res (/myproject/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/fetch/index.js:193:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:474:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:363:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
  type: 'FETCH',
  sourceUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  code: 'EAUTH',
  command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2' }
```

Comment: Esta es una copia de [mi pregunta original en SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722201/nodemailer-whit-gmail-smtp-oauth2-autentication-is-getting-me-invalid-status-co)

Comment: ¿Pusiste el modo offline en la configuración de OAuth 2 en el playground de Google?

Comment: No estaria encontrando la opción. ¿Y porqué sería necesario esta opción activada?

Comment: Es lógico, el refresh token tiene como función **permitir un acceso continuo** a la API, esto quiere decir, que no necesariamente el usuario debe estar logueado. Se supone que debes configurar tu aplicación en Google para tener acceso. En [este link](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) lo configuras y en el menú superior del engranaje elijes la opción offline en *Access type*.

Comment: Yeap. Todo configurado, incluso el mode offline active...no encuentro referencia por ningun lado respecto al error. Sospecho que es algo de las URLs a las que le estoy pegando